# Adopt (and reopen!) SO's closed code-golf questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Our site budded from StackOverflow as an outlet for code-golf questions when the need for reigning-in the focus of SO became apparent. [<-this is all guesswork, am I right?]

This has left a sizeable wasteland of closed golf questions on SO. Can we have 'em?

...Do we want them?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think we want all closed questions tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) from SO.

- Some will be duplicates (e.g. [Fibonacci code golf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232861/573420) vs [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/194))
- Some are off-topic (e.g. [Most interesting and challenging programming tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/364155/573420) or [What's the point of Perl golf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72383/573420))
- And some are just completely boring (e.g. [Code Golf: Shortest python program to convert from celsius to fahrenheit and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9270207/573420) ).

There are even more *unclosed* questions tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) on SO: regardless of their quality we wouldn't want 250 questions dumped on this site *en masse*.

However, there are some gems there, which raises a variant question:

> Should we make a list of good [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) questions from SO which we might ask to be migrated here.

Certainly SO is not keen on those questions continuing to be active: when I posted a new answer to one of them a few months back it led to the question being protected almost immediately. Migrating over here could give them new life, and improve the quality of this site. The potential downside I see is the rep effect: some people might not like having considerable rep transferred from their SO account to a brand new PCG account.

Comment: An option would be to copy them instead of migrate - which would then of course lead to the exceptional case of do-not-close-as-duplicate-although-it-is.

Comment: Almost all of those questions were made "community wiki" on SO, so will there really be a "rep effect"?

Answer (score 3):

A list of the "good" (IMO) questions that would be nice to *emigrate* to our site. To avoid the flooding issue, perhaps they could be transferred one-a-day or so, and labeled "Classic:" and maybe marked Protected. I'll add more to this. This is a selection from the oldest 2 pages of golf questions on SO. Of course, they're too old to "migrate" by the normal mechanism, I'm assuming technological solutions exist to migrate these in a special manner.

#### Rosetta Stone.

28 votes 16 stars 50 answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228518/palindrome-golf
24       9        36         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232861/fibonacci-code-golf
2        5        40         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237496/code-golf-factorials
21       10       63         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350885/create-sort-and-print-a-list-of-100-random-ints-in-the-fewest-chars-of-code
8        4        32         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372668/code-golf-how-do-i-write-the-shortest-character-mapping-program
24       9        45         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383403/code-golf-print-the-entire-12-days-of-christmas-song-in-the-fewest-lines-of-c
17       4        31         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394574/code-golf-new-year-edition-integer-to-roman-numeral
30       23       46         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407518/code-golf-leibniz-formula-for-pi
2        0        2          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412184/code-golf-diffie-hellman-key-exchange
24       11       22         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445782/finding-closest-match-in-collection-of-numbers
7        6        26         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464960/code-golf-combining-multiple-sorted-lists-into-a-single-sorted-list
1        0        5          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613390/code-golf-encode-decode-ascii-binary
11       8        16         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795027/code-golf-hex-to-raw-binary-conversion
1        0        5          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744671/golf-expand-templates-in-text-file
18       11       14         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831915/code-golf-automata
75       52       43         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928563/code-golf-evaluating-mathematical-expressions
12       7        13         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038252/code-golf-quickly-build-list-of-keywords-from-text-including-of-instances
46       32       17         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066234/the-skyline-problem
10       7        34         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078770/array-searching-code-challenge

#### Regular Golf.

5        3        7          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966896/code-golf-shortest-code-to-find-a-weighted-median
17       13       13         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031466/evaluate-dice-rolling-notation-strings

#### Disputed.

{This Answer is CW. Please feel free to "line-item veto" any questions in the above list and place them here.}

1        1        6          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679802/codegolf-work-out-the-prime-factors-of-a-given-number (this one needs editing, but the answers are nice)

#### Appendix.

{I don't know what to do with this one. It belongs somewhere, but ....}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921455/how-do-i-program-using-cat

Comment: Should I add more to this answer or is this enough of a *first wave*? I noticed the next few in my search panel are LiraNuna's. I wonder if those should be considered separately.

Comment: Did you check for duplicates? A few of those look quite likely to have dupes, and one I explicitly flagged up as a dupe in my earlier answer.

Comment: No, I haven't checked for dupes, yet.

Comment: Can we rescue the deleted ones somehow?   Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364869/code-golf-who-has-the-best-poker-hand/3392025#3392025

Answer (score 2):

You can't migrate posts that are [more than 60 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)... Judging by [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-golf%5D+created%3A..2013+is%3Aquestion) that means that 98.2% of all (undeleted) questions tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) on Stack Overflow are ineligible for migration.

Of the 4 that are eligible for migration 3 had nothing to do with golfing ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316378/projecting-an-n-dimensional-array-to-1-d), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228761/trying-to-simplify-this-javascript-function), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508159/altering-a-list-using-append-during-a-list-comprehension)) so I've removed the tag. This means that there's [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128929/compress-ascii-to-unicode-python), which might be on-topic (I'm not 100%) and it's asking for help rather than posing a challenge.

If you're serious about migrating questions from Stack Overflow you'll need to be organised. Have a feed of all questions tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf); remove the tag, if it's not applicable and flag using the "other" option if you want it migrated. You have to do this before it gets downvoted and deleted, which can be extremely quick (not that I have any idea of the proportion of questions that this happens to with this tag.)

To be honest, I'd be quite surprised if you got many good new questions out of Stack Overflow...

Comment: [@LiraNuna](http://stackoverflow.com/users/41983/liranuna) asked a lot of good golf questions. I'd like to see those represented here. Looks like we have to copy them though :(